# How to Check if a string exist in another string with github action?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I have a github action, i have a list of words like this:

```
'["alpha", "beta", "preview", "experiment"]'
```

and i have a suffix string like this:

```
suffix = steps.get-version.outputs.version-suffix
```

now i want to check if any of words in list exist in suffix or not?
currently i am using this:

```
 - run: echo "IS_PRE_RELEASE=true" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV    
   if: contains(fromJson('["alpha", "beta", "preview", "experiment"]'), steps.get-version.outputs.version-suffix)
```

but there is an issue:

if

```
suffix = beta
output: IS_PRE_RELEASE updated to true
```

if

```
suffix = beta1
output: IS_PRE_RELEASE does not set
```

so issue is, only **beta** (alpha,...) accepted and other type of string does not accepted (beta1, beta.1,....)

i tried to change `contains` to `startsWith` but i get same result.
how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a windows os in your action, you can use powershell commands:

- name: Run PowerShell script
  run: |
  # Define the list of strings
  $list = @("beta", "alpha", "preview")

  ```
      # Define the suffix variable
      $suffix = "Beta134"

      # Loop through the list and check if the suffix starts with any item
      foreach ($item in $list) {
        # Convert both strings to lower case for case-insensitive comparison
        if ($suffix.ToLower().StartsWith($item.ToLower())) {
          # Set the PREX environment variable to true and exit the loop

          echo "IS_PRE_RELEASE=true" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
          break
        }
      }
  ```